# How to verify a PHP hashed password in a NodeJS app

Tags: php, node.js, hash, passwords

My application ran on PHP for years, and I used the recommended [password hashing API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) as of PHP 5.5 to store my users' passwords.  For instance:

```
$password = password_hash("my password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

As a result, my database is full of passwords such as this:

```
$2y$10$sjzYz7g/kVxpJUynC/...........pjKPh0z1QuU.Mlt7TVAiPW
```

Now I am moving my application to run on `NodeJS 12.3.0` instead of PHP and I now use the [`bcrypt` library](https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js#usage) like this:

```
const saltRounds = 10;
const password = await bcrypt.hash("my password", saltRounds);
```

The same password hashes to something like:

```
$2b$10$SYZH5Mj4Dy8dkKyRv1O/.........XNGPVBe8nPJjpnEjPZxx.
```

I thought that the algo, salt and rounds used were within the string so that the transition would be seamless.  However, when I try to verify a password that had been stored by PHP, the correct password fails verification:

```
// result === false
const result = await bcrypt.compare("my password", phpStoredHash);
```

I really hope I don't have to force all users to reset their passwords.  How can I verify the passwords PHP stored in my `NodeJS` application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [bcryptjs](https://github.com/dcodeIO/bcrypt.js) package instead. It can compare php generated hashes correctly.

```
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

const hashPHP = "$2y$10$Lsn001yN38WssfQmJ5hM5.Ywa3AKB76YD/zUC9QNS5BPRr9QMWOTa"
console.log(bcrypt.compareSync("my password", hashPHP));  // outputs: true
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll verify this today.  My issue aside, do you have any insight about the pros/cons of using `bcryptjs` instead of `bcrypt` in Node?  The latter is also very popular but hasn't been updated in 3 years

Comment: @BeetleJuice Sorry, I have no deeper knowlegde. Just happen to know the solution you asked for. Been there, done that.

Answer (score 0):

working my end  when you use **bcrypt.compareSync**  require `const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')`  use this  npm

> npm i bcryptjs

let ifmatch = bcrypt.compareSync(Password, users.password);

```
      if (ifmatch == false) {
        res.status(401).send({
          message: "password not found",
          status: 0,
          result:ifmatch,
          err
        });
      }
      if (ifmatch == true) {
        res.status(200).send({
          message: "You are successfully logged in",
          users,
        });
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

This does not have any salt rounds,PASSWORD_DEFAULT uses BCRYPT

```
$password = password_hash("my password", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Try to make following change :

```
$password = password_hash("my password", PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Changing the PHP code does not help me because all the passwords have already been hashed and stored in the database.  The problem is how to verify whether a cleartext password matches the exiting stored hash from a NodeJS application